# Windows portable class library WCF Service

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, portable-class-library

I have the following problem: 
I created windows wcf service, which I published to a server.
Furthermore I developed a portable class library to communicate with the service (added a service reference). To test the correct behaviour I set up a Windows 8.1 app. On the computer I did all these steps everything is working fine and the communication with the wcf service works just great.

But here comes the problem: I checked out the sampe project on another computer and an EndpointNotFoundException occured. How can this happen? Same project, just a different computer. Are there some configuration files in the windows 8 app missing?
I have really no clue and therefore I would be really grateful for your help.

Comment: Ok I guess I was completely wrong. I tried to include the service reference in the windows 8 app itself and on the other computer it is still not working. When I'm connected via VPN on my own computer everything is fine. 
So I set up a normal Windows Console application and this one is working on all the PCs. 
Therefore I analyzed all the inner exceptions in the win 8 app and somehow there seems to be a problem with the access privileges of the socket but I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: So I have figured out the error: In Package.appxmanifest was the capability "Private Networks" missing. Therefore it wasn't possible to run the app in the private network itself. Oh my god, so silly.